# Call a class method as soon as an object it extends is created

Tags: php

Assume we have the following class (simplified):

```
class SuperConfig {
    public $mainDir;

    public function setDir() {
        $this->mainDir = "path/to/dir";
    }
}
```

This class is supposed to be extended in EVERY other class in the project, and I do need the `setDir()` function of the parent to be executed. Obviously, I could do it like this:

```
class A extends SuperConfig() {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::setDir();
    }
    // ... other stuff is about to be done ...
}
```

and I could access the properties in the child class like this:

```
class A extends SuperConfig {
    public function doSomething() {
        SuperConfig::mainDir;
    }
}
```

This is a viable solution, but I got multiple hundreds of classes and doing this in every single one seems tedious. So, is there a way to do something like this:

```
class SuperConfig {
    public $mainDir;

    public function __extend() {
        $this->setDir();
    }

    public function setDir() {
        $this->mainDir = "path/to/dir";
    }
}
```

`__extend()` obviously doesn't work like that, but I'm wondering is there is a trick how I could make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SuperConfig {
    public $mainDir;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setDir();  // consider moving setDir's code here as well,
                          // unless you have a good reason for it to be a method
    }

    public function setDir() {
        $this->mainDir = "path/to/dir";
    }
}
```

You simply do this, and then you expect all subclasses to call the parent constructor *if* they're overriding the constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // more code
}
```

It's perfectly reasonable to expect children to call their parent constructor, unless they deliberately want to leave the instance in an unknown and potentially broken state.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even think about calling the parents constructor directly. Not the solution I had wished for, but certainly better than what I came up with. Thanks a lot. :) Oh, and the `setDir()` is actually way bigger and the constructor does more too. So, to keep the code readable, its better in another method, but for simplifying the problem, I just created the mini-version of the config.

Answer (score 1):

Put the constructor in the class that is being extended.

```
class SuperConfig {
    public $mainDir;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setDir();
    }

    public function setDir() {
        $this->mainDir = "path/to/dir";
    }
}
```

In any class that extends `SuperConfig`, if they have a constructor also, be sure to include `parent::__construct();` so that `setDir` is called.

Answer (score 1):

**Read deceze's answer for an actual solution to your problem.**

I would like to point out tho, that you should not extend every class in your project from a Config class. There are several ways how you could improve that.

**1.)** Create a static config class which you simply can call everywhere without the need of creation

```
class SuperConfig {
    protected static $mainDir = null;

    public static function setMainDir($dir) {
        self::$mainDir = $dir;
    }
}
```

**2.)** Create a trait rather then a parenting class.

```
trait SuperConfig {
    protected $mainDir = null;

    public function setMainDir($dir) {
        $this->mainDir = $dir;
    }
}
```

which you then can use inside your classes:

```
class XYZ {
    use SuperConfig;

    public function doSomething() {
        $this->setMainDir('path/to/your/dir/');
    }
}
```

Note that you can do that in the constructor too (which is kinda what you want).

Im not saying those two solutions are the best, but I dont like the thought of extending all classes from a config class. Just does not make much sence. Just imagine that you can only extend from one class per time, while you can use as many traits as you wish (and also have as many static classes as you need).

Comment: I'd love to work with traits, I really don't like the current solution either, but the project I'm working on is on PHP 5.3 which doesn't allow the usage of traits and I can't think of a better solution in 5.3.

Comment: I would go for a static class in your case anyway. Makes more sence then traits. Just wanted to show you possible workarounds for your problem :)

Comment: Yeah it's looking way better, I didn't really like the solution of having access to these properties in all the classes. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this particular case you just need:

```
class SuperConfig {
    public $mainDir = "path/to/dir";
}
```

Comment: The class I showed here was just for displaying the problem. The actual class `setDir()` is named `reconfigure()`, sets 19 properties and calls 5 methods. So I can't just do it like that since none of the properties is a hardcoded string.